# cooking on a hot&humid day

Tags: kitchens, air-conditioning, ventilation

I have 2 window air conditioners in my house. None of them seem to have a setting to bring in (a little bit of?) fresh air. When we cook, the house becomes a bit smokey. Also, the vapors of freshly cut onion can can be felt even in the rooms adjacent to the kitchen. On cool days, I open the windows and place a fan near a window to drive out air from the house (and get in fresh air from other windows). But what is the best solution on hot&humid days when turning off the AC and using the above method is not an option?

Comment: Do you have a hood vent? Ideally you'd have a hood vent that vents to the outside. Barring that, you could use a recirculating hood vent. Otherwise, on hot and humid days, maybe consider salads.

Comment: Thanks @DA01 I have a recirculating hood vent. That doesn't seems to help much. Perhaps I need to change the filters.

Comment: @abishek you might be able to find replacement filters that use charcoal inserts. That might help with the filtering.